# Powershell - shutdown command - capturing errors and logging them

Tags: powershell, logging, shutdown

I'm still very new to powershell and thanks to you all, and some previous posts I've learnt a lot so everything is self taught.  I needed a script to run as a task on a central machine, to ensure all the others are shutdown daily.  I've managed to get this working as I needed.  But I saw an error and I'm hoping someone one here is kind enough to help edit the script and explain the changes and how they work in general!

The script works as needed.  But if a machine responds to ping, the script sends the shutdown command.
Which is all good until there is an issue like WinRM or the password is worng ect.
The script logs the ping and logs the shutdown as sucessfull when it isn't.  The bit I have not worked out is how to capture errors and output them into a text file so I can see later the results.

I've tried several things and never worked.  I'll thank you all in advance and stay safe

```
#shutdown machine

$susername = "User_Name"
$spassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$spsCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ($susername, $spassword)

############################################################################################

# running commands

cls
write-host "Shutting down netowrk machines

"
$currentTime = Get-Date -format "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
write-host "$currentTime - Program Luanched."
Add-Content $PSScriptRoot\Shutdown_Log.txt "*****************************************************************************"
Add-Content $PSScriptRoot\Shutdown_Log.txt "$currentTime - Program Luanched."

$Computers = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\PC_List.txt
Foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
{
    #Ping Test. If PC is shut off, script will stop for the current PC in pipeline and move to the next one.
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 1 -Quiet)
    {
        # If responds.  Do this....
        write-host "$computer Responding - Continuing...."
            Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock { Shutdown /s /f /c "IT Daily Shutdown" } -credential $spsCred
        $currentTime = Get-Date -format "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
         write-host "$currentTime - $computer - Responded.  Shutting down machine..... "
         Add-Content $PSScriptRoot\Shutdown_Log.txt "$currentTime - $computer - Responded.  Shutting down machine..... "
    } else {
        # If no response - then do this.....
        $currentTime = Get-Date -format "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
         write-host "$currentTime - $computer - did not respond, moving on.... "
         Add-Content $PSScriptRoot\Shutdown_Log.txt "$currentTime - $computer - did not respond, moving on.... "
    }
} # bottom of foreach loop

$currentTime = Get-Date -format "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
write-host "$currentTime - Program Terminated."
Add-Content $PSScriptRoot\Shutdown_Log.txt "$currentTime - Program Terminated."
```

Comment: Have you had a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-exceptions?view=powershell-7)? Basically, you should learn about try/catch.

Comment: ah ok - that's interesting.  I have tried and thought I was going down thw wrong path.

Do you have any scripts where you've used this so I can see, or can u mod mine so I can start to see. I struggled to follow the guide previously.

Comment: Basically it's as simple as `try { .. do all your stuff .. } catch { .. error handling...}`. Execution will jump immediately to the catch-block as soon as any error is encountered in the try-block. You can acces the error record inside the catch-block with `$_`. Of course you can make as many try-catch regions as you like and even nest them inside each other. But that's all better explained in articles you can easily find on the web.